# Find the bars indexes in the largest Rectangular Area in a Histogram

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, image-processing

I have an histogram and I need to find the indices of the bars inside the largest rectangle under the histogram.
The way to find the largest rectangle under the histogram is explained in this link

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangle-under-histogram/

and in many other links on the web. I'm not able to retrieve the indexes of the bars inside the output rectangle.
Any ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link that you have posted:

> For hist[tp], the ‘left index’ is previous (previous to tp) item in stack and ‘right index’ is ‘i’ (current index).

So you have to edit the getMaxArea() method to store the left and right indexes of the max area:

```
int getMaxArea(int hist[], int n)
{
// ..
int rindex=0;
int lindex=0; 
 while (i < n)
{
//..
            if (max_area < area_with_top)
            {max_area = area_with_top;
            lindex=i-(max_area/hist[tp])+1;
            rindex=i;
            }
//..
}
while (s.empty() == false)
{
//..
            if (max_area < area_with_top)
            {max_area = area_with_top;
            lindex=i-(max_area/hist[tp])+1;
            rindex=i;
            }
//..
}
//..
cout << "indexs: " << lindex << " " << rindex << "\n"; // u may pass them to main method, if needed
return max_area;
}
```

Im not a c++ programmer, so you may optimize my try,
You can find the edited code here: [ideone: online compiler](https://ideone.com/U002tZ)